# Webpack with typings.json

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I've been looking at this blog tutorial - http://www.jbrantly.com/typescript-and-webpack/ on creating a bundled JS file that combines the code from a Typescript project and its libraries that is uses (such as jQuery in the link) and bundles it using webpack.

While the tutorial is good (and I've had it working as expected), it's now out of date in that tsd.json files are replaced with typings.json and so far I've been unable to create a dummy project like the tutorial in the link but using typings.

So any ideas on what config is required or how do I use typings (https://github.com/typings/typings) and use webpack to bundle up code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the *typings* and *tsd* project behave very similar. Especially when it comes to include the typings into you project.

*typings*, as does *tsd*, will but all your installed typings ([see this for how to install new typings](https://github.com/typings/typings#quick-start)) into a `typings` directory. Inside that directory a file called `index.d.ts` is placed. This file contains all the references to the installed typings.

When you're building your TypeScript project make sure that the `index.d.ts` ist part of your `files` property inside the `tsconfig.json`. For example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "..": ".."
    },
    "files": [
        "typings/index.d.ts",
        "src/index.ts"
    ]
}
```

Where `src/index.ts` is the entry file for the project. You shouldn't have to edit anything when it comes to *webpack*.

If you want to have an example, [this](https://github.com/PTW-Freiburg/udi) is a project I did a while ago. **But** since I do not have a `files` property in my `tsconfig.json` the TypeScript compiler finds the definition files by itself.

Comment: Thanks, after for too long I noticed that I hadn't placed the line at the top of my TS file -  import $ = require('jquery');
This meant that IntelliJ didn't complain, and when I used webpack it also didn't complain.  Bundled up the code, but just without the jQuery import.  It was listed in my typings folder and index.d.ts - which is why I'm guessing IntelliJ could find it.

So lesson is make sure to include imports if you want it bundled. Not a fan of marking my own answers as correct, so I'll give you it.

Answer (score 2):

You install typings -

1. npm install typings
2. typings install dt~jquery --save --global  (this installs the d.ts for jquery)
3. Make sure that you include the import - e.g. import $ = require('jquery'); in your TS file.  IDE's such as intelliJ will compile your code fine without it - but webpack will not see jQuery and therefor will not include it without it.

Everything else will be the same as the tutorial link.